# Accidentally used fuel containing methanol while my car's manual says I should avoid it. Big deal?

Tags: fuel-system, elantra

I recently fueled at a gas station with a sticker on the pump saying "contain methanol". Later I found out on the manual (of my Hyundai 2017 Elantra) that fuel with methanol should be avoided.

I already drove on the fuel for a few hundred miles. No obvious issue is observed so far. Should I be worried?

Answer (score 1):

One tank probably no, so top up often to dilute the remainder.

Hopefully you have not done this before...

Some car manufacturers use seals in the fuel systems that are incompatible with some additives and the seals degrade or swell over time. This can be one issue faced by those who run diesel engines on "homemade bio-fuel" for example.

Most manufacturers have since upgraded the seals in their fuel systems so that the newer cars don't have this issue. For those using older cars you have to pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

Where in the US can you find gasoline without alcohol ? Cars have been made for decades to tolerate ethanol additions. And as @ solar mike says one tank won't bother any thing : I put several percent ethanol in cars from the '50's with no ill affects . I added it during especially cold weather to absorb water , I didn't even know I was being an envionmentalist. (I could get the ethanol for free).

Comment: Shell does not put ethanol in its gas according to this article>>>>>>https://driving.ca/auto-news/news/why-you-dont-actually-want-ethanol-in-your-gas-tank

Comment: Every dealer in the US puts in a minimum of 10% ethanol. Little irony , the ethanol I used long age came from Shell.